# Jenkins kubernetes plugin return ConnectionShutdownException

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I deployed Jenkins on Kubernetes cluster.

I trying to configure slave on demand using jenkins-kubernetes plugin on the same cluster.

Over http, timeout response is returned.

Over https, this is always the same error:
WARNING o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesCloud#provision: Failed to count the # of live instances on Kubernetes
okhttp3.internal.http2.ConnectionShutdownException

This is the configuration

[image: service account]

[image: cluster config]

What I have forgot ? Thanks.

Comment: Did you check Jenkins Syslog? Also, may I know what is the purpose of creating Secret Text?

Comment: There are no logs about  the connection (on the jenkins GUI) Maybe available on another location ?

Comment: Where are running your K8s cluster?

Comment: I created cluster on Digital Ocean, and use bitnami/jenkins image

Comment: could you please try with `https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/` image or `stable/jenkins` helm chart?

Comment: It works with stable/jenkins, (I set serviceType: LoadBalancer to get an IP). Thank you very much ;)